# actionlayout on menuitem does nothing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

i am setting an actionLayout on a menu item and setting background color and image, but it's not respected. in my activity, i have:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.submit_action, menu);
```

my submit_action is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_submit"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/check"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

my check layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="lol" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but even with all of this setup, this is how the action bar appears, not showing my menuitem at all (but it's there, because it responds to the click, but doesn't appear):

[image]

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Try `app:actionLayout="@layout/check"` instead of `android:actionLayout="@layout/check"`.

If you're using `ActionbarSherlock` or `AppCompat`, the `android:` namespace will not work for `MenuItem`s. This is because these libraries use custom attributes that mimic the Android APIs since they did not exist in earlier versions of the framework.

Comment: And by `app:actionLayout` he means the name of your app package.  So if your app package name is twitter it would be `twitter:actionLayout`.

Comment: @clu you can use whatever you want. The default is to use "app"

Comment: @clu No, app is a defined namespace within the XML. It refers to the applications compatibility libraries. If app doesn't resolve, paste xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in your <xml> tag.(Yes, old comment, putting more information here to help those that might google).

Comment: Don't forget to change to support library 23.1.0 Otherwise the menu xml will let you use actionlayout and not complain, but it won't work. `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'`

Comment: My layout is always on the right and setting the gravity does not work and how can you use the item without a title? didnt you get a lint error??

Comment: This is absolutely HORRID. BOTH `android:actionLayout` AND `app:actionLayout`? Wasted hours on this, inflating my own custom layout programmatically, even writing an entire Medium article lamenting that `android:actionLayout` is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

when using Appcompact  ,menu item will be like

```
<item android:id="@+id/cart"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_cart"
    android:title="@string/action_cart"
    app:showAsAction="always"
 />
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Ben Harris is absolutely correct. However, in some case like when using attributes like:

```
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```

used in SearchView (in my case), the layout view isn't shown and that caused a lot of headache to me. It seems that collapseActionView  is not supported with action view in appcombat. So consider this as well while doing your stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

use app namespace instead of android and it will work fine.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_submit"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/check"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```