# Null pointer exception while adding value on menu item in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to display some dynamic text on menu item. This is my code so far.

Menu file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/Cart"
    android:title="Cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:title="Cart2"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart"
    app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

actinbar_badge_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <!-- Menu Item Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cart" />

    <!-- Badge Count -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my2, menu);
    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();

    TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    tv.setText("12");
    return true;
}
```

It is giving null pointer exception error in

```
TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
```

Can anyone help me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) menu.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
```

instead

```
TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211761/actionlayout-on-menuitem-does-nothing).
Briefly - try to use `app:actionLayout` instead of `android:actionLayout`.