# How to change menu item to textview android

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I want to reduce the size of my application. I have multiple images that can be removed to reduce the size.
Some of this images used in my toolbar menu items as icon. I want to change the `<item />` to be `com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView` can i make that ?
I can add any item to my menu programmatically but this will make a big change in my code. Can any one help me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your menu layout you should put something like :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:title="@string/add"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    tools:visible="true" />
```

Comment: I know that, But I want to make it icon text view not item or replace it's drawable with icon

Comment: @AhmedZainy check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211761/actionlayout-on-menuitem-does-nothing