# Does android:actionLayout in Menu Folder to Create Android Action bar not work?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm creating an Android Action Bar using menu directory. While I was creating a new bar, I wanted to customize this action bar, so I added action-layout in one of items in xml file under menu directory. here is what I did

menu_main.xml(under menu directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:title="refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"/>
<item
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
    android:title="setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

in second item, i added actionLayout and search_layout.xml is just simeple LinearLayout
with TextView and EditText.

search_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ffad8745"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="#ffad8745"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My expectation was that the first and third item show icons whereas second item shows me a layout that I defined, but here's what i got: only the title that I defined in menu_main.xml.
[image]

I eventually made an action bar that I wanted, but I still don`t quiet understand why the way initially tried does't work. please help me out. thank you

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228941/9715339 ,it might help

Comment: @MayurGajra thank you it helps